# Is the function $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $(R, B)$, where $B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, be our measurable space.

In this measure space how do you that the function $$f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$$ is measurable?

Comment: Is $R$ the real numbers $\mathbb R$?  Are you asking to *prove* that the floor function on $\mathbb R$ is Borel measureable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: in particular, it's a countable sum of step functions, so is a uniform limit of step functions, so is regulated, and all regulated functions are measurable.

Comment: Thank you. Say mathematically how would this look? I understand the concept but how do you show in maths terms that it is regulated? Is there another word for it?

Comment: What I just said is "mathematical". I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "mathematical" that doesn't include it, honestly. For what a regulated function is, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_integral).

Comment: Apologies. I've just never heard my lecturer use the term so I wasn't sure. Thank you I shall look into it.